# Is this the right way to import gsap in vue.js (it works but is it the "right" way?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, libraries, gsap

I'm quite new to Vue.js and have had some problems getting libraries to work without getting the "error  'X' is not defined  no-undef" message.

In this case it is 'Back' that is not defined (which is a part of GSAP)
I figured the only place to "define" Back would be in the import.

Is this just the way to import libraries?
Do I have to write every undefined part in the import like this?
It works but it just seems unnecessary.

```html
<template>
  <div id="mainTemplate">
    <h2>This is the MainTemplaye.vue Component</h2>

    <div ref="box" class="box"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { TimelineLite, Back } from "gsap";

export default {
  name: "MainTemplate",
  mounted() {
    const { box } = this.$refs;
    const timeline = new TimelineLite();

    timeline.to(box, 1, { x: 200, rotation: 90, ease: Back.easeInOut, })
    timeline.to(box, 0.5, { background: 'green' },'-=0.5')
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Any variable needs to be imported/declared if you are going to reference it. The exception is if it is available globally, such as if you've registered it on window (`window.gsap = gasp`), but this is not best practice.

If you don't want to import things everywhere, you can register them in a vue plugin and they'll be available on the component (`this.$gsap`). But only do this with things you are really using frequently as it bloats your components.

Comment: Thank you @Josh Dean, that was what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're learning from, but you're using the old syntax of GSAP. If you use the new syntax of GSAP you don't have to import anything other than `gsap` in your case:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";

export default {
  name: "MainTemplate",
  mounted() {
    const { box } = this.$refs;
    const timeline = gsap.timeline();

    timeline.to(box, { duration: 1, x: 200, rotation: 90, ease: 'back.inOut' })
    timeline.to(box, { background: 'green' }, '-=0.5')
  },
};
```

The best place to start learning is [the official GSAP Getting Started article](https://greensock.com/get-started/).

Comment: Okay, interesting, i overlooked the date of the article it's from 2018.

Link to article: https://blog.usejournal.com/vue-js-gsap-animations-26fc6b1c3c5a

The funny thing is that GSAP links to this article in the official GSAP Getting Started article.

I would love to upvote, but im to low rep.